# DevicePolicyManager isProfileOwnerApp with Kitkat api 19 or lower

Tags: security, android-5.0-lollipop, profile, android-4.4-kitkat

Correct me if I am wrong with my assumptions. I amlooking into DevicePolicyManager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html) isProfileOwnerApp method that check if the device is enforcing the enterpirse profile with require security like encryption etc. This method is add in class DevicePolicyManager from api 21 (lollipop). Can this be implements on devices running less than api 21 that is 19 and lower. If so how to do so, did not find much on google.